# OpenCV SFM Xcode 7.2: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: cv::sfm::reconstruct

Tags: opencv, xcode7, opencv3.0, 3d-reconstruction

I have linked to all the appropriate libraries and headers in my Xcode project (where I have the samples files from OpenCV for scene_reconstruction), after building and installing OpenCV with the contrib module.

I have also applied the `#define CERES_FOUND true` fix that is recommended here:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/issues/476

The editor prompts me with the correct functions completions from the sfm module and the reconstruct.hpp file (except that the prompts I get have the last boolean is_projective flag missing from all reconstruct()'s i.e.:

one of the prompts is:

```
reconstruct(<#const std::vector<std::string> images#>, <#OutputArray Rs#>, <#OutputArray Ts#>, <#InputOutputArray K#>, <#OutputArray points3d#>)
```

I however get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"cv::sfm::reconstruct(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in scene_reconstruction.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when I build the project.

I did a camera calibration in the same project and it ran fine, and everything else is alright, I have been using OpenCV built from source for years now, so I've taken care of the basics.

How do I proceed to fix/probe the issue further?

Comment: Hi there. My experience here is that the community would prefer it if you did not add requests for urgency in your posts, especially in your titles. Remember that everyone who helps here is a volunteer, and as such they will answer at their leisure. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Apologies, I didn't think about it from that angle earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with CERES_FOUND not being set because of a version mismatch between eigen and ceres.